# http request get url variable

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

Hi I try to get the result of a php query with an http request and get it with `$GET[]` in php. I checked my database there should be one row that match. What cause this?

The PHP error I receive is:

> **Warning:** mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...

```
var text= $("#username").val();  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("resultt").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://website/project/readusern.php?username="+text,true);
        xmlhttp.send();


        }
```

**readusern.php**

```
    $searchuser = $_GET["username"];
    $myname = $_COOKIE["userid"];
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','pw','db');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }



    $data = "SELECT * FROM user 
    WHERE username = $searchuser
    AND id != $myname
     ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $data);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

//echo results

    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Your SQL query is not only wrong but vulnerable to SQL injection. Strings should be quoted in SQL queries, but you should be using parameterized queries anyway which would prevent this problem and several much worse ones.